# Sometimes when booting computer hangs on BIOS splash screen

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, motherboard, bios

I have a desktop computer with an Asus P8Z68-V LE motherboard. It has a Wester Digital 1 TB hard drive, Samsung SSD, DVD/CD drive, an external hard drive that is always connected to a USB 3 port and sometimes additional USB flash drives.

Sometimes when it is starting it hangs on the BIOS screen (the one that has "Press F1 to enter options"). When I do press F1 I can enter options. I noticed there's a boot option I don't recognize: "WD virtual CD 0748 1025".

Any tips on trouble shooting why the computer sometimes hangs when booting? The SSD is primary and the HDD is secondary. I only have windows 8 installed (though I use several VMs).

Comment: “A small portion of drive space on your new My Passport or My Book hard drive has been used to create a Virtual CD (VCD). The VCD contains the WD SmartWare installation software, the encryption and password protection application, User Manuals, and other resource files. The VCD looks like an actual CD volume and appears on the screen each time you connect your WD drive to the computer. “  If you want to disable it follow this guide: http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=3wy5gr

Comment: @Techpumpkin_WD yes I do have that, but do you think it could be causing the hanging issue?

Comment: I don't really think it could be causing it. But if you have USB storage devices connected all the time make sure to remove them from the BIOS boot order. http://superuser.com/questions/18669/why-is-my-pc-boot-time-slow-when-usb-hdd-attached

Comment: As @Techpumpkin_WD states, the issue is clearly that the WD external drive appears to be bootable because of the software. If you do not use that VCD (i.e., you do *not* use WD encryption), just uninstall it. You could also unplug the external HDD, or in BIOS, change boot order so that it is the last item or removed completely.

Answer (score -1):

If the hang doesn't go away unless you power cycle, you may need to reflash your BIOS.  If the hang is merely an extended wait on the BIOS splash it is possible that there is some kind of issue with your boot sequence.

To rule out an issue with any system files related to booting, run `sfc /scannow` from an administrator command prompt and allow it to complete.

As to the WD Virtual CD, it's possible your VM software has a virtual disk drive somehow enabled at the BIOS level.